# Loading DataTable content without losing control with Javascript from another page

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, datatable

I try to call html content from Page2.html to Page1.html dynamically like this:
(Using Datatable https://datatables.net/)

**Page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onClick="loadData()" value="load">
<div id="contenuPage2"></div>


</body>
<script>



function loadData(){

    $('#contenuPage2').load('Page2.html #example');
}

//data
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A'],
];


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    } );   
} );



</script>
```

**Page2.html**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

But this method doesn't work (when I click on load button)

The final result must look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>

</body>


<script>

//contenu de ma dataTable
var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A'],
];


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    } );   
} );
</script>
</html>
```

How can I call correctly the DataTable from Page2.html in Page1.html

Thank you for your help.

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is most likely that you are calling the `dataTable` function before the table has been inserted into the page (DOM). If `$('#example')` returns no DOM elements (which it will on page load), then `dataTable` won't have anything to run against.

You should probably use an AJAX request with a callback function and call `dataTable` there:

```
$.get('Page2.html', function(resp) {

var dataSet = [
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 4.0','Win 95+','4','X'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.0','Win 95+','5','C'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 5.5','Win 95+','5.5','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 6','Win 98+','6','A'],
    ['Trident','Internet Explorer 7','Win XP SP2+','7','A'],
    ['Trident','AOL browser (AOL desktop)','Win XP','6','A'],
];
var example = $(resp).find('#example');
$('#contenuPage2').html(example);

$('#example').dataTable( {
  "data": dataSet,
  "columns": [
      { "title": "Engine" },
      { "title": "Browser" },
      { "title": "Platform" },
      { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
      { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
  ]
});  
);
```